# UIWeb View Crashing Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am using the following use for `webview`

```
let url = NSURL(string: "")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!); webview.loadRequest(request)
```

When i click on the first button the app crash even if it do sent launch the `web view`

> 2016-01-17 21:04:45.632 HHKNBK[38603:34872679] Unknown class
>   _TtC6HHKNBK6button in Interface Builder file. 2016-01-17 21:04:45.633 HHKNBK[38603:34872679] Unknown class _TtC6HHKNBK6button in Interface
>   Builder file.fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value(lldb)

Bad Instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional unwrapping to prevent crashes.

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "") {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    //...
}
```

Comment: if let url = NSURL(string: "") {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url); webview.loadRequest(request)

            //...
        }

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and check which line causes the crash

Comment: i fixed it but now new problem (lldb) the problem has i had custom class on uibutton which could not be found